# Oracle Read stored procedure output from another stored procedure in other database

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I thought this will be straight forward operation, but it seems not

I have two Oracle databases, in the same Oracle server
Lets say BigDatabase and SmallDatabase, each have a stored procedure

Now I need the stored procedure in BigDatabase to call the stored procedure in SmallDatabase AND TO READ ITS OUTPUT

The output is an integer number

Comment: You just need to set up a database link, and call proc@dblinkname.

Comment: @TonyAndrews I did, the problem in reading the output, it throws an error when I try to

Comment: What error?  Always helps to know!

Comment: Based on the limited information you've provided (no example, no error message), if I had to guess... if your procedure takes parameters, you probably tried schema.remoteproc(parameter)@dblink, but the syntax is schema.remoteproc@dblink(parameter).  Could this be your problem?

Comment: @KrisJohnston, while I'm preparing my example, I found that the issue is not in the out parameter itself, but in any insert or update satement to fill this out parameter this solution was to use " PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;" in the child stored procedure

Comment: Many thanks for you guys